# Setting up my family sharing : what will happen to the content previously purchased by the children?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, apple-id, family-sharing

I'm currently setting up the family system for me and my two children. We were previously using the account of one of my children for us three, and having the usual problems with messages being delivered to the 3 Iphones and the Macbook, etc, etc. Thus, all the music / app / video purchases have been made with this account.

So I'm planning to create two more accounts (for me and my 2nd child), and use my (new) account as the family organizer. The previous account will be a "child" account.

My question is : what will happen to the content purchased on our previous account ? Will it be shared with the family ? Will it just remain account-specific ? I'm not really concerned by the pictures, music and the rest as I can save it and restore it later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually need this very answer myself, with the added plot twist that more than one account to be joining the family has purchases.

Answer (score 2):

Content from any member account is sharable, whether old or new - Apps, Books, Tunes etc.

Specific data points from those apps, though, will be lost if the account using them is not the same as previously.

For example, UserA was the original account. UserB & UserC are added as family members. UserA & UserB had previous purchases, different to each other. UserC is new & 'virgin' but is the new Family Organiser account.

UserC can regain any & all previous purchases made by Users A & B, but will lose account-specific data such as email [including the userA@icloud.com account entirely], iMessages, any game progress or reading bookmarks etc they had prior to the 'handover', as they all still belong to UserA.

Similarly for UserB, but they will retain their existing user-specific data on existing apps etc.

Comment: Okay, I'm not concerned about the account-specific data anyway. Thank you !